# how to send numpy array over python socket

Tags: python, numpy, sockets

- Hey , Good day !
- I implement a simple program to send a numpy array over python sockets

**This is server.py**

```
import socket
import numpy as np

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1024))
s.listen(5)
print('Server is ready...')

while True:
    client, adr = s.accept()
    print(f'Connection to {adr} established')
    myarray = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
    client.send(myarray)
    client.close()
```

**This is client.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1024))

getarray = s.recv(100)
print(getarray)
```

- **I want to send myarray in server.py to client.py**
- **I want to get the myarray in client.py 100% similar to the myarray in server.py**
- **But, When I run server.py and client.py , client.py's output is this .. **

`b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'`

- **I don't know what is the encoding method (asci or utf-8 to decode that code)**
- **How can I decode it ?**

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried looking up this issue? Python sockets are pretty well documented

Comment: It looks like it just sent the numbers in the array in 32-bit little endian format (probably how they are stored in memory without any encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pickle to encode the array object into bytes, and then send that.
Although depending on the size of the array you may need to change the way you receive it, s.recv() will only get a certain number of bytes, so you would need to send the size of the array in bytes over first, and then repeat s.recv until you have the entire array. `pickle.dumps(obj)` will return the byte stream of the object, and `pickle.loads(obj)` will return the original object once all of it is received.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yes, it worked, thank you veryyy much    :)